# Distribution limit of delta function

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

I want to find the limit in  $D$$'$ (${\Bbb R}$) of the following distribution : $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\delta _\frac{p}{n}$.

I thought about separating the sum of the delta function, since it is $\infty$ when $p$ is equal to $0$, and $0$ with the other value of $p$. 
$\frac{1}{n }(\delta _\frac{0}{n}+\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}\delta _\frac{p}{n})$ , so the first part of the sum is $0$ and the second part is $\infty$. But computing the limit of all of this will give indeterminate form. 
Any idea of how to deal with this ?

Comment: Do you mean $\delta(p/n)$?

Comment: If $T_n$ is the distribution and $\phi$ a test function, then $\langle T_n, \phi \rangle = {1 \over n} (\phi(0)+\cdots+\phi({n-1 \over n}))$. The limit is what?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the notation.

Comment: What does $\delta(p/n)$ mean?

Comment: Isn't this just the integral operator?

Comment: Let it act on a test function $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}.$ Then it is just $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \varphi(p/n),$ which should look familiar.

Comment: Maybe think Riemann?

Comment: @copper.hat yes the support of the test function is compact, but how can we define the limit from all of these definition ?

Comment: Forget distributions for a moment. Pick a fixed smooth function $\phi$. What does ${1 \over n} (\phi(0)+\cdots+\phi({n-1 \over n}))$ converge to? Maybe draw a little picture.

Comment: I think it will converge to $0$ ?

Comment: @14max Not to $0$ ! But to the measure/distribution associated with the  characteristic function of unit interval $[0,1]$ (think to a probabilistic interpretation).

Comment: @14max Are you familiar with Riemann integration? If $\phi(x) =1$ on $(-1,2)$  then it certainly cannot converge to zero.

Comment: @copper.hat not at all

Comment: Hmm, distribution theory without integration will be a challenge. The above is an approximation to $\int_0^1 \phi(t) dt$.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your responses. Maybe I'll dig a little bit deeper in distribution theory and integration. Can you just give the step to tackle this problem ?(let's suppose I know all of the background necessary )

Comment: @14max All the steps necessary are above.